# Regex matching the first instance

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I have a regex `(.*)?start((?!(foo|boo)).)* end test.*`.

What it does is it will return true if there is no **foo** or **boo** in between **start** and **end test** and false otherwise. It is working as expected. But I am facing issue with the below expression

```
start foo again start too anything anything end test
```

My expected result is false because `foo` is there in between. But looks like it is not taking the first `start`.

Comment: In the end, do your regex needs to accept string like `abc` that does not contain at all `start` and `end test`?

Comment: I wonder if the down vote was because you said it is working as expected, then your question is why isn't it working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using this pattern:

```
^(?:(?!\bstart\b).)*\bstart\b(?:(?!\b(foo|boo)\b).)* end test\b.*$
```

The reason your current regex is failing is that the initial `(.*)?start` is actually consuming `start foo again`, hence getting around the negative lookahead tempered dot which checks that `foo` and `boo` do not appear in between.  My approach consumes at the beginning *only* if the word be not `start`.  This lets your logic work as expected, and we can assert that neither `foo` nor `boo` appear in between the very first `start` and the `end test` text.

Note that I added word boundaries in a few places, and also made the groups non capturing, assuming you don't want to capture anything.

### Demo

Answer (score 2):

[Tim Biegeleisen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229/tim-biegeleisen) answer is great but it does not accept strings in which `start` and `end test` are not present (example: `abc123` should be accepted as the condition *there is no `foo` or `boo` in between `start` and `end test` is respected*) . It is not obvious from your question if you need those strings or not. If you do then, you have to change the regex into:

```
 ^(?:(?!\bstart\b).)*\bstart\b(?:(?!\b(foo|boo)\b).)*\bend test\b.*$|^(?:(?!\bstart\b).)*$|^(?:(?!\bend test\b).)*$
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/492Z5m/2/